# fabric.js how to mask or clip the canvas with png image

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

[image]

I need to mask all canvas objects using one layer. Layer is a png file which I loading from URL. What is the best approach for this?

Tried this way. But I need to clip every object. And I think this is not the proper way to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/w396uhnv/

```
<button id="btnAddText" >Add Text</button>
<canvas id="divPad" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></canvas>




var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('divPad', {
      width: $("#divPad").width(),
      height: $("#divPad").height()
  });


  $("#btnAddText").click(function () {

      var text = new fabric.Text("Testing", {
          fontSize: 50,
          fill: "green",
          top: 50,
          left:50
      }); 
      canvas.add(text);
      text.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
      canvas.renderAll();
  });
  var background;
  fabric.Image.fromURL('http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Rid/Bjo/RidBjoni9.png', function (objects, options) {
      background = objects;
      background.set({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          scaleY: canvas.height / background.width,
          scaleX: canvas.width / background.width,
          selectable: false
      });
      canvas.add(background);
      canvas.renderAll();
  });
```

Comment: as I understand, there is no way to clip by PNG. But if you can create one-path SVG - it's simple )

Comment: Using `image.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';`  is the correct way to do it. The masking image should be that last image draw to the canvas.

Comment: your method is already the good one. You won't find anything simplier. draw png shape, set globalCompositeOperation to 'source-atop', draw artwork, thaen reset globalCompositeOperation to 'source-over'

Answer (score 1):

i created a jsfiddle where i create some objects and i assign pattern to them.
is that what you need?

if so, i show a snippet below and my jsfiddle exmaple.

javascript , actually the main code:

```
   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

//create circle object
 var circle = new fabric.Circle({
                  radius: 60, 
                  fill: 'red', 
                  left: 50, 
                  top: 100
                });
            canvas.add(circle);
addPattern(circle);

//create square object
var square = new fabric.Rect({
              left: 180, 
              top: 140,
              fill: 'green',
              width: 140,
              height: 180
            });
            canvas.add(square);
addPattern(square);
canvas.renderAll();



function addPattern(obj){
  fabric.util.loadImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function (img) {

                obj.fill = new fabric.Pattern({
                    source: img,
                    repeat: 'no-repeat'
                }); 
                canvas.renderAll();
    });
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/t6vf5z5w/

[image]
hope helps, good luck.

Comment: is it possible to drag and resize the position image pattern within the shapes

Answer (score 0):

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('/userboards/board-img/mask-no-dots.svg', function(objects,options){
        $scope.overlayPath = new fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects,options);
        $scope.$apply();

    }, function(item, object){

    });


$scope.cutByMask = function(){
        if($scope.overlayPath){
            canvas.remove($scope.overlayPath);
        }

        $scope.overlayPath
            //.scaleToHeight(533)
            .set({
                //left: 797, top: 1368,
                scaleX: $scope.zoom / 100, scaleY: $scope.zoom / 100
                //, width: 2811, height: 533
            })
            .setCoords();

        canvas.centerObject($scope.overlayPath);

        canvas.add($scope.overlayPath);

        canvas.moveTo($scope.overlayPath, 0);

        canvas.remove($scope.overlayPath);
        canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
            if($scope.overlayPath){
                $scope.overlayPath.render(ctx);
            }
        };

        canvas.renderAll();
    };
```

Variant with SVG mask. Here you load SVG mask (SVG with only one path), and then all your images will be cropped by this mask.

I don't found variant with cropping by PNG, but if you need it - you shoud use it in

```
canvas.clipTo
```